# Prove that $H$ is generated by the elements $(1,2)$ and $(0,3)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H:= \{(x,y) ∈ ℤ×ℤ : 5x-4y≡0 \bmod{6} \} $.

Prove that $H$ is generated by the elements $(2,1
)$ and $(0,3)$.

Comment: Well. $\,(1,2)\notin H\,$ so it hardly can be a generator...Perhaps you meant $\,(2,1)\,$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Note $\rm\ mod\ 6\!:\ \color{#C00}{{-}5}x\equiv \color{#0A0}{-4}y\iff \color{#C00}1x\equiv \color{#0A0}{2}y\iff x = 2y\!+\!6n,\:$ for some $\rm\:n\in \Bbb Z.\:$ Thus $\rm (x,y) = (2y\!+\!6n,y) = y\,(2,1)\! +\! n\,\color{#04F}{(6,0)} = (y\!+\!3n)\,(2,1)\!-\!n\,(0,3)\, $ by $\rm\, \color{#04F}{(6,0)} = 3(2,1)\!-\!(0,3)$.

Comment: love it ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that $(2,1)$ and $(0,3)$ are in $H$. To prove the reverse inclusion you should show that every element $(x,y)$ of $H$ is of the form $m(2,1) + n(0,3) = (2m, m + 3n)$. To do this you should show that if $(x,y) \neq (2m, m + 3n)$ for any $m$ and $n$ then $5x-4y \neq 0$ mod 6.

Comment: Did you notice the OP did **not** write $\,(2,1)\, $ but $\,(1,2)\,$ ?

Comment: Right, but I saw your comment and assumed that you'd correctly spotted a typo.